# twilio - how to make an outbound voice call in php

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have the below method.  Currently is just calls up an external phone number and says "Welcome".  I cannot understand how to connect a twilio number with an external phone number by voice?  Lots of example of how to do text-to-voice but not much on voice to voice.  Any pointers appreciated.

```
public function test_call(){
    $this->account_sid = 'AC-account_sid';
    $this->auth_token = 'myauth_token';
    $this->client = new Client($this->account_sid, $this->auth_token);
    $call =  $this->client->account->calls->create(
      '+81xxxxxxxxxx', // Destination phone number
      '+81yyyyyyyyyy', // Valid Twilio phone number
      array(
          "record" => false,
          "url" => "http://development.example.com/gomi.xml")
      );
    if($call) {
      echo 'Call initiated successfully';
    } else {
      echo 'Call failed!';
    }
}
```

Contents of gomi.xml

```
 <Response>
 <Say voice="alice">Welcome</Say>
 </Response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect your call there to another number, then you need to look at the [`<Dial>` TwiML verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial).

You could, for example, update your `gomi.xml` to:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>+XXXXXXXXXXXX</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Then, when the initial call connects it would trigger another call to the number inside the `<Number>` tags, connecting the two callers.

Take a look at [the documentation for `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) for more information.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there anyway to call the originating number BEFORE the destination number?

Comment: Yeah, switch the number you use in your REST API call with the number you use in the TwiML response.